# Hide items according to date difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of files which opens via modal. What I want is that it should hide the file 30 days after the file was generated.

Here's the code that displays the files

```
 <table>
                @foreach (FileInfo res in Model.PDFFile)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@res.Name.Splitter('_', 1)</td>
                        <td>
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#testmodal@(res.Name.Splitter('_', 0))">View Result</a>
                            <div class="modal fade" id="testmodal@(res.Name.Splitter('_', 0))" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Close"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <embed src="~/Files/@res.Name" width="850" height="1000" type="application/pdf" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
    </table>
```

And here's the controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ResultModel rmodel = new ResultModel();
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        rmodel.PDFFile = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf*");
        return View(rmodel);

    }
```

The filename includes the date of the file. Do you have any idea how to do this in javascript ? Thanks !

Comment: Why not just filter them in the controller before you send the collection to the view?

Comment: And why do you need the date included in the file name? The `FileInfo.CreationTime` property will contain the date the file was uploaded/created in the directory so you should be just filtering based on that using a simple linq query

Comment: can you give an example linq query ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point sending all the files to the view and then hiding them in the view (you might be generating html for a hundreds of files but only showinh a few) and you should just filter them in the controller. In addition, its not clear why you would need to include the date in the file name itself, as `FileInfo` contains a `DateTime CreationTime` property that you can use for filtering based on the date the file was uploaded.

To filter the files in the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DateTime minDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    ResultModel rmodel = new ResultModel()
    {
        PDFFile = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf*").Where(x => x.CreationTime > minDate);
    };
    return View(rmodel);
}
```

And assuming you remove the date from the filename, then you can just pass a collection of file names to the view rather that a collection of `FileInfo`, for example

```
ResultModel rmodel = new ResultModel()
{
    PDFFile = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf*")
       .Where(x => x.CreationTime > minDate).Select(x => x.Name);
};
```

where `PDFFile` is `IEnumerable<string>` rather that `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` (although its not clear what your `Splitter()` extension method is actually doing)

Comment: `DateTime maxDate = DateTime.AddDays(30);` returns an error saying, _An object reference is required fro non-static field, method, or property 'System.DateTime.AddDays(double)'_

Comment: Oops, that should be `DateTime maxDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);` assuming you want 30 days before todays date.

Comment: See edit. But having read the question again, I'm now a bit unsure of your logic. Do you want to see only files that were created in the last 30 days (which is what the edited code will do)

Comment: But it needs to be 30 days after CreationTime.

Comment: OK, that's what the edits to the answer will do (it will exclude all records with a `CreationTime` less than 24th April (based on today being 24th May)

Comment: But the 30 days would be dependent from today's date not from the CreationTime, so that would make it not really exactly 30 days since it will count 30 days before the date.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. If a file was created on 1st Jan 2016 it would be excluded, but if it was create 10th May 2016 it would displayed. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: If a file is created May 11 2016 then it should be displayed from May 11 to June 10 but will be excluded on June 11 onward :)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the code will do. If you view the page today, it will be included, but if you view the page again on the 11th June it will be excluded.

Comment: Okay. Sorry, my bad. Got confused there. Thanks :)